# Confused about WindowBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I know this is not a programming issue, but I couldn't find any solution for two days. I have installed *Windows builder* and created my first hello world app, but something is wrong with the controls.

For example, this line

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hello world");
```

gives me output.

[image]

What is wrong?

or type something `jtextField`

[image]

Comment: Seems unlikely to be a WindowBuilder problem. Look over the code it generates maybe? (There's nothing special about WindowBuilder-generated code - you should get the same result as if you'd typed all the code yourself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a problem of your graphics card rendering poor quality images. Like greg-449 suggested, look at stackoverflow.com/q/22737535/2670892